# Resize text to fit div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 `container` holding 3 columns on screen sizes above breakpoint **md** (`col-md-4`).

In each column I have an `img` of class `img-fluid` that has a text description that appears on hover. I want to have this hover text scale appropriately with the responsive resizing of each `img-fluid`, so that it always fits on top of the image precisely.

**Im my current attempt, as the images resize the text overflows its container - I want to stop this from happening by responsively resizing the text to fit the container**

I've tried [fitty](https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty), which works beautifully for normal text, but doesn't affect my hover text in the way I was hoping.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a better (ideally using existing bootstrap 4 classes) way of achieving this?

```js
// fitty('.fit');
fitty('#my_fit');

fitty('#fit1');
fitty('#fit2');
fitty('#fit3');
```

```css
.hvrbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: rgba(11, 11, 28, 0.71);
    color: #fff;

    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179); /* for old browsers */
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: none;
}
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"/>
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>


<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row border">
    <div id='my_fit'>Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="hvrbox zoom">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom"
                     height="350" width="350">
                <div class="fit hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" width="350" height="350">
                    <div class="fit" id="fit1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="hvrbox zoom">

                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom"
                     width="350" height="350">
                <div class="hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" width="350" height="350">
                    <div class="hvrbox-text fit" id="fit2">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
                        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="hvrbox zoom">

                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom"
                     width="350" height="350">
                <div class="hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center fit" width="350" height="350">
                    <div class="hvrbox-text fit" id="fit3">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                        doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
                        architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
                        aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
                        sequi nesciunt.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fitty@2.2.6/dist/fitty.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although it doesn't use fitty, [this](https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/scale-typography-screen-size/) article may help. It described how you can use `vw` as a unit to scale font-size based on your browser width.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the text overflows? Shrinking font-size? Truncated text?

Comment: you just want it to stay on top?

Comment: I think its work perfectly in regular desktop as well as all media queries without using this // fitty('.fit');
fitty('#my_fit');

fitty('#fit1');
fitty('#fit2');
fitty('#fit3');

Comment: @ksav - yes I want to think the font size to prevent overflow

Comment: default minSize for fitty is 16. Did you try lowering it?

Comment: "Fitty scales the font size of multi-line text to always fit the container height rather than width", it's the normal behavior of the plugin. It's not yet implanted to take into account the height as you can read [here](https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty/issues/9). I think that you should try and search for another plugin or another way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this want you want to happen? i use media query. try to resize any size on browser.

```css
 .hvrbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: rgba(11, 11, 28, 0.71);
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  /* for old browsers */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: none;
}

#fit1, #fit2, #fit3{
 margin: 25px;
}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px){
 #fit1, #fit2, #fit3{
 margin-top: -35px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 991px){
 #fit1, #fit2, #fit3{
 margin-top: -120px;
 font-size: 10px;
}

}

@media (max-width: 767px){
 #fit1, #fit2, #fit3{
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-size: 15px;
}

}

@media (max-width: 320px){
 #fit1, #fit2, #fit3{
 margin-top: -20px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  <title>Title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row border">
      <div id='my_fit'>Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="hvrbox zoom">
          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom" height="350" width="350">
          <div class="fit hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" width="350" height="350">
            <div class="fit" id="fit1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="hvrbox zoom">

          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom" width="350" height="350">
          <div class="hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" width="350" height="350">
            <div class="hvrbox-text fit" id="fit2">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="hvrbox zoom">

          <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000601617732/9e87878ffdd67333ac8b81f9da22696a_400x400.jpeg" alt="person" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block zoom" width="350" height="350">
          <div class="hvrbox-layer_top img-fluid d-flex align-items-center fit" width="350" height="350">
            <div class="hvrbox-text fit" id="fit3">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
              quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty/blob/gh-pages/dist/fitty.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an OK approach but not very generalisable, in that I have to hard code the font size per breakpoint

Comment: here hope this one help you https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/hover-effect-style